# Unable to make API call in NextJS app running on port different that port 3000

Tags: next.js, cors

I am currently a CORS issue in my NextJs App. When I run the app on let's say on **localhost:3030**, and I make an API call to http://some-api.com, I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://some-api.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3030' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

I added the following lines to the next.config.js.

**process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_HOST=http://some-api.com**

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_HOST + '/:path*'
      }
    ]
  },

  //avoiding CORS error, more here: https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_HOST},
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

But it still does not work.

I also attached of the response header on the OPTIONS call.
I can see that the access-control-allow-origin is set to http:localhost:3000 I think if I override that value to localhost:3030 it would work but I am not sure how to do that.

I am pretty new to NextJs, so some help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating the CorsFilter on the Back end API to allow response to http://localhost:3030 solved the problem.

My back end API is written in Spring Boot.

So I added the following:

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3030");
```

**Note**: It also possible to allow all with "*"